# WP8.1 c# Onedrive SDK : download badrequest

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, onedrive, universal

I have a project which now doesn't work when I download binarie from onedrive like PNG. I got a bad request in query response. I take some backup and they have the same problem. This was working few days ago I have not modify anything. Is there a changne in the api ? I download xml with no problem whith same query.
I try to test apigee console and it seems to work. Anyone has same problem ? Got solution ?
THANKS a lot

I go this response from api :
StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request'

Comment: If you are looking for technical support for the OneDrive API, please consult the teams issue tracker https://github.com/onedrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues.  Additional be sure to include the details of your response to get the quickest response.Stack Overflow is built for programming questions, not support, your questions will be better served there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that find their way here, the problem in question is a result of some proxy servers rejecting the URLs when they contain single path segments with more than 260 characters. Unfortunately this is possible with the URLs that the OneDrive API generates, and so we're investigating changes to resolve this kind of problem.

The issue can be tracked at https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/143